# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am upgrading jpa, hibernate, spring, and jdk to enable the new features from JPA 2.1.  But I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

I have read other postings about this, but they do not resolve the error on my machine.  For instance, [SJuan76's answer to this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431153/getting-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-table-indexes-while-performing-jp) suggests upgrading to jpa 2.1, but I have set the eclipse jpa project facet to version 2.1 and I have also included `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` in my pom.xml.  You can read all the versions of the various libraries in the complete pom.xml [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/4uC5ssP2AfF7HrW84Roe?b=EKq81LlN7Did4OzmAEOR).  **What do I need to change in the pom.xml or in the eclipse project to resolve this error?**

**Note: I can get rid of the error by changing the hibernate version in the pom.xml back to `<hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>`, but this defeats the purpose of upgrading.  Does the fact that changing the hibernate version turns the error on and off help us to diagnose the problem?**

If the problem is multiple jars conflicting with each other, I could use the eclipse type manager to disable one of the jars, but which jar would I look for?

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
ERROR ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Oct 28, 2014 11:01:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 21 more
```

Comment: maybe same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I already read that posting.  The question and answer are related to the play framework, which I am not using in this project, so I think this is a different question, unless you can show a specific thing I can do in my eclipse to resolve this error.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 I just added a note in my posting that toggling the hibernate version can turn the error off and then bring the error back again.  Does this help identify the solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case the culprit was javaee-api and glassfish libs that didn't support JPA 2.1

Comment: Wish I'd seen this earlier! Yes, Glassfish 3 does not support JPA 2.1:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/18447541/2083907

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Jboss 7.1.1, jboss already has `hibernate-jpa-2.0` in its classpath, so during runtime it uses the one in its classpath, not the one you've deployed with your app. To point jboss to the version that you want (`hibernate-jpa-2.1`) do the following:

1. copy `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final.jar` to the following directory : `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/javax/persistence/api/main`
2. open `module.xml` and change the resource-root as follows :
   `resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final.jar"`
   (pointing it to jpa 2.1)
3. re-compile and re-deploy your app, then you are good to go.

Answer (score 7):

I spent a lot of time on this.

For me, it was the javax.persistence.jar conflicting with hibernate jars.

I removed the persistence.jar and it started working.

Comment: Three hours of frustration, solved in three lines of information

Answer (score 1):

you can import hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar.
it is not ejb3-persistence.jar.

Answer (score 1):

In case of JBoss7, you should replace the api jar in jboss7/modules/javax/persistence/api with updating module.xml file with the updated jar file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure out which dependency is bringing the wrong JPA. To do this use maven dependency:tree. The output is pretty straightforward and you will be able to determine what to exclude.

To exclude do something like this:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Sorry I can't help more but with the information you provide, this is all I can do.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue in my project by excluding the Hibernate ejb3 lib that was included via a transitive dependency.  The dependency from maven dependency:tree was as follows:

```
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
```

In my project, this was originally included in the executable jar my build process produced, via the maven assembly plugin. To exclude this (and other libs), I used the assembly plugin's dependencySet configuration in src/main/assemble/test-jar-with-dependencies.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>test-jar-with-dependencies</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>    
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>org.eclipse.persistence</exclude>          
            <exclude>org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA</exclude>
            <exclude>org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA</exclude> 
            <exclude>org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 and thank you for looking into this.  I still have not solved the problem, but I am approaching it from a different direction in a different posting.  Are you willing to help me with the different posting?  I suspect the solution lies in figuring out which jars to exclude and what syntax to use to do so. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789225/namedentitygraph-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type