# upgrade hyperjaxb3 to jpa 2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, hyperjaxb

I am trying to upgrade to JPA 2.1 in an eclipse project that uses maven, jpa, hibernate, and hyperjaxb. I am getting the following error when I try to do `Run As..Run on Server` from within eclipse:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

**I ran `mvn dependency:tree` on the root folder of the project and the problem seems to be that hyperjaxb3 is using JPA 2.0, which conflicts with JPA 2.1.  Is there some way to get hyperjaxb3 to use JPA 2.1?  Or is there some other way to resolve this error so that my app can have the benefits of JPA 2.1 without having to remove hyperjaxb3?**

Here is the output I got from `mvn dependency:tree` on the root folder of the eclipse project from the windows command line:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyApp 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ MyApp ---
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] org.springframework.samples:MyApp:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3:hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3:hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip:jar:0.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-testing:jar:0.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:3.1.0.CR8:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:3.1.0.CR8:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.6.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.8.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:7.0.42:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:7.0.42:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.13:runtime
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time-hibernate:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time-jsptags:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.2.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery-ui:jar:1.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:jquery:jar:2.0.3-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4:runtime
[INFO] +- com.github.dandelion:datatables-jsp:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.dandelion:datatables-core:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.dandelion:datatables-export-itext:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.dandelion:datatables-servlet2:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.eclipse.emf:common:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.805s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 06 12:32:32 PST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/124M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you please specify which JPA 2.1 dependency you want to use? I mean `groupId:artifactId`.

Comment: Ok, I'll assume [`org.hibernate.javax.persistence`:`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api) and [`org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.7.Final`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.7.Final) then.

Answer (score 1):

You get the conflicting `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` because of the `org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3:hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip` dependency which has it in `compile` scope. This is actually incorrect, [should be](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/issues/13) `provided` instead. The `hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip` may safely assume that JPA API as well as `hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime` are provided. This will be corrected in the future release.

First of all, make sure you really need `hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip`. This is only needed if you generate the roundtrip test case - which is actually only meant for "playground". In production projects you should normally not need this. So you may very well turn off the roundtrip test case generation and remove the `hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip` dependency.

Next, if you do need `hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip` you can use Maven's mechanism of [dependency exclusion](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions) to exclude the `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` dependency from being transitively excluded because of the `hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip`. This will look something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you already include `hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime` directly, you may also exclude it from `hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip`.

Next, I've just tried out JPA 2.1 compatibility in [this test project](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/tests/po-jpa-2.1). I had to update `hsqldb` to `2.3.2` but apart from that, it worked with `hibernate-entitymanager` version `4.3.7.Final` and `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` version `1.0.0.Final`. The test is not *especially* representative, but it is a good indication that Hyperjaxb is compatible with JPA 2.1. JPA 2.1 is most probably backwards-compatible with JPA 2.0 so actually the code generated by Hyperjaxb should be compatible to JPA 2.1 as well.

I have now filed two issues, one to just [move Hyperjaxb to JPA 2.1](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/issues/14), the other one to [support new JPA 2.1 features](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/issues/15).

Moving to JPA 2.1 should be quite simple as it will (hopefully) only require to update the dependency versions and in a few cases (like `hibernate-jpa-2.x-api`) also artifact ids. HSQLDB must be updated to `org.hsqldb:hsqldb` version `2.3.2` and later, but this is no big deal. I will implement it in the next release.

Supporting new JPA 2.1 features is much more work.

---

> Now a small side note. When posting links to jumpshare an other external resources, please clearly state the license or a legal status of the linked resource. I will consult pro bono only on sources which could be safely added as tests or samples to the project in the benefit of *all users*.