# I've got an error for Java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I tried to connect **h2** database and web app using hibernate and JPA, but I receive this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fcim.png)
I create table with name Person in h2 database with name Students.
I was used IntelliJ IDEA with JPA, Hibernate and H2 integration for the new WebProject.

This is my **persistence.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="StudentPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/Students"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="doncho"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults"
                      value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Bean:

```
package com.beans;
import javax.persistence.*;    
@javax.ejb.Stateless(name = "StudentBeanEJB")
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class StudentBean { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String passWord;
    @Column
    private String email;

    public StudentBean() {
    } 
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }   
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And I tried to add new student with class AddPerson:

```
public class AddPerson {

    public static void main(String [ ] args){

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StudentPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();


        StudentBean addStudent = new StudentBean();
        addStudent.setId(0);
        addStudent.setUserName("username");
        addStudent.setPassWord("pass");
        addStudent.setEmail("d1521@abv.com");

        em.persist(addStudent);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }

}
```

I tried to "persist" with hibernate for first time and I'm little confused how to configure persistence.xml file correctly.
I would be grateful for any ideas to resolve this error.

Best regards,

D. Balamjiev

Comment: The error message points to incompatible jar files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes() while performing JPA query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431153/getting-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-table-indexes-while-performing-jp)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734540/nosuchmethoderror-in-javax-persistence-table-indexesljavax-persistence-index

Comment: i.e use search on this site for your error message